# IIViewDeckController is not working when push by navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iiviewdeckcontroller

Please help me in my project. I am using `IIViewDeckController` but its not working when pushed by view controller

Heres the hierarchy:

`ViewController` (Push)----> `IIViewDeckController` (with Left and centerview).

Here is my code when initialising the IIViewDeckController:

```
- (IIViewDeckController*)generateControllerStack{

self.navigationView = [[NavigationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavigationViewController" bundle:nil];
self.profileView = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController* navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.profileView];


IIViewDeckController *deckView = [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:navC leftViewController:self.navigationView rightViewController:nil];

deckView.leftSize = 50;

[deckView disablePanOverViewsOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView")];

return deckView;
```

}

then this is my code when I'm pushing IIViewDeckController using another ViewController

```
- (IBAction)signInAction:(id)sender {

IIViewDeckController *deckView = [[UIManager sharedItems] generateControllerStack];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:deckView animated:YES];
```

}

Thanks you very much guys :)

[image]

when I clicked sign in which is I will push my iiviewdeckcontroller with left and centre view this appears

[image]

Comment: Show some code what you've done and what is the issue.

Comment: Hi! I follow the same instructions given in the documents i just add a view controller as home page. when I clicked the button it will pushed iiviewdeckcontroller with left and centerview. It appears that the centerview is not showing.

Comment: Its better to show it by screen shot or coding rather than textually...

Comment: you want to push viewcontroller or just want to push like side menu?

Comment: I have a view controller and a button with it. I will push IIviewdeckController with left and centerview. using the button in the view controller. my problem is the iiviewdeckcontroller is not working it appears that the centre view is not showing.

Comment: Check again, if  you have setup the centre and left viewcontrollers properly

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that.

```
//Appdelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"
                                                       bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;

}
```

import `IIViewDeckController.h` in `ViewController.h`  then

```
- (IBAction)GoToNext:(id)sender 
{
        IIViewDeckController *objIIVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your VC's Identifier"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objIIVC animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you created it like this? 
I am using it as root view controller. and it is working fine

```
    UINavigationController* navController=(UINavigationController*)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

    SlideMenuViewController* slide=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SlideMenuViewController"]; /


    IIViewDeckController* deckController =  [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:navController
                                                                                    leftViewController:slide
                                                                                   rightViewController:nil
                                                                                     topViewController:nil
                                                                                  bottomViewController:nil];

    float leftSize=self.window.frame.size.width - (88*self.window.frame.size.width)/320;
    deckController.panningMode = IIViewDeckFullViewPanning;
    deckController.leftSize =leftSize;
```

Comment: Hi i am not using storyboards. I'm using nib files :)

Comment: IIViewDeckController is not my rootviewcontroller. I am using another view controller and set the iiviewcontroller as childviewcontroller

Comment: Can you please update above code lines with the new ones?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

*- (IIViewDeckController*)generateControllerStack{*

```
self.navigationView = [[NavigationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavigationViewController" bundle:nil];


UIViewController *centerController = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
centerController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:centerController];


self.viewDeck = [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:centerController leftViewController:self.navigationView rightViewController:nil topViewController:nil bottomViewController:nil];

self.viewDeck.leftSize = 50;

[self.viewDeck disablePanOverViewsOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView")];

return self.viewDeck;
```

}

Comment: The issue is in 4th, line,  change that to "UINavigationController* navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:centerController];"

Comment: its still not working :( I can't move on to my project because of this problem :(